# How to include resources and bundles with Addons?

Tags: plone

When making a plone 5 addon, how do we add our own resources to the registry now? (aka our own css and js to the outgoing bundles?)

I've read http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/resourceregistry.html and it isn't helpful...

Can someone point me to a working example of a collective addon or some better addon documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vangheem's [example.plone5resource](https://github.com/collective/example.plone5resources) in the collective on github has examples of several strategies. The examples vary with the extent to which you need requirejs to handle dependencies and whether or not you want the resources compiled by the bundle manager. "Legacy" bundles are the easiest if you're updating a Plone 3 or 4 resource.

Comment: I keep getting an error which then breaks the whole thing. http://pastebin.com/hgJmyt5c

Comment: Your registry.xml is faulty, you shouldn't put an <element> tag inside `<value key="js">`. See: https://github.com/collective/example.plone5resources/blob/master/example/plone5resources/profiles/default/registry.xml#L7 That's why you got an absent string method error in your traceback.